# Phaser3 - Add acceleration and drag to vehicle on Physics arcade engine

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a simple top down car game in Phaser3. At the moment, my car moves at a constant speed.

However, I would like it to behave more realistically, with elements such as drag/friction/acceleration applied to it, a bit like the example at http://domasx2.github.io/gamejs-box2d-car-example/.

How do I get it to behave this way using the Phaser Physics arcade engine (which the rest of my game currently uses).

My code is as follows:

```
import Phaser from "phaser";

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: "phaser-example",
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    arcade: {
      debug: true
    }
  },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update,
    render: render
  }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
let platform;
let player;
let cursors;

function preload() {
  this.load.image("car", "https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/car90.png");
  this.load.image("sky", "https://labs.phaser.io/assets/skies/gradient11.png");
}

function create() {
  this.add.image(400, 300, "sky");

  player = this.physics.add.sprite(400, 300, "car", 1);
  player.body.setBounce(20, 20);
  player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

  cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

  this.physics.add.collider(player, platform);
}

function update() {
  player.body.velocity.x = 0;
  player.body.velocity.y = 0;
  player.body.angularVelocity = 0;

  if (cursors.left.isDown) {
    player.body.angularVelocity = -150;
  }
  if (cursors.right.isDown) {
    player.body.angularVelocity = 150;
  }

  if (cursors.up.isDown) {
    this.physics.velocityFromRotation(
      player.rotation,
      150,
      player.body.velocity
    );
  }
  if (cursors.down.isDown) {
    this.physics.velocityFromRotation(
      player.rotation,
      -150,
      player.body.velocity
    );
  }
}

function render() {}
```

Stackblitz demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/phaser3-typescript-d6zbzf.

Comment: Can you please share an example of how this would work? Kinda struggling with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For drag, you can add this statement to your `create()` function:

```
player.setDrag(0.90);
```

Against constant speed, you can change your `update()` section to this:

```
  if (cursors.up.isDown) {
    // Go faster
    player.body.acceleration.setToPolar(player.rotation, 100);
  }
  if (cursors.down.isDown) {
    // Brake
    let speed = player.body.velocity.length();
    player.body.acceleration.setToPolar(player.rotation - Math.PI, 2 * speed);
    if (speed < 3) {
      // Come to a full stop
      player.body.setVelocity(0);
    }
  }
```

Instead of setting the velocity, this sets the forward acceleration to a fixed number. The code above doesn't allow the player going backwards. This may not be what you want.

You could also prevent turning if speed is slower than a certain number, e.g. 3.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to implement this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/phaser3-typescript-d6zbzf but the acceleration doesn't continue when I let go of the forward key. Also the brake doesn't seem to be working. Could you please have a look and help me?

Comment: The car stopped immediately after letting go of the keyboard because of these lines: `player.body.velocity.x = 0`. I commented them out: https://phaser3-typescript-psbdac.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thanks, there is still some eccentric behaviour with the braking. The car should slow down to a halt then pick up speed when reversing. It seems impossible to do. And the collisions on the edges seem to a bit crazy haha.